# How to create new environments with create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, configuration, environment-variables, create-react-app

I am using [react-scripts v2](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3815) (beta) and I have read the documentation [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env).

We need to create many environments.

- We want to store env file under folder `config/env`.
- We might use javascript file in `config/env/staging.js` because `.env` seems to be only for root directory.
- We have real environment :

  - default
  - development
  - staging
  - preproduction
  - production
- We expect the `default` environment to be a default config under version control in `config/env/default.js`, it must be the default configuration used when doing `npm start`
- We expect the user to be able to override with a file with no version control. (something like `config/env/default.local.js`

Basically that can be reduced to two issues :

1. Is it possible to relocate env location folder?
2. How can we create and select a new environment on `npm start/build`?

without ejecting.

Comment: are the docs not sufficient? https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env

Comment: No it does not. Did you read it? Let me know if you find anything anywhere where they tell you how to create new environments.

Comment: It does talk about different environments, just not about location of the folder, which is simple to overcome. left one possible answer of many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the environment file to `.env` before starting / building. You can even put `.env` in `.gitignore` that way

```
"start": "cp $ENV .env && react-scripts start"
```

Then run it:

```
ENV=config/staging/.env npm start
```

There are lots of ways of doing what you want without ejecting, since it's all preprocessing (before your app starts / builds).